# Acessing SonarQube web from external host

Tags: web, webserver, sonarqube, host

I run a SonarQube server on an Ubuntu 14.04. From the server's machine, there is no problem accessing to SonarQube web, but from my machine I cannot.

I looked at access.log and sonar.log but there is nothing about my access.
On configuration of sonar ( sonar.properties ) I tried some different configurations: for sonar.web.host, I tried to leave it commented, set it with 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, and my public IP; for sonar.web.port I tried to set it on 80, 9000 and 8080; and for sonar.web.context, I have it set to /sonar.

The ports are open because I installed an apache server and I can access to it without any problem.

Do you have some idea about what's happening?

Thank you